# Laravel - Como Alterar pasta padrão para novos projetos

Tags: laravel

Os novos projetos criados utilizando o instalador do Laravel vão para `C:\Users\MyUser\`.

Por exemplo se eu usar o comando `laravel new MyApp` o Laravel será instalado dentro do diretório `C:\Users\MyUser\MyApp`.

Como faço para alterar esse caminho para outro, por exemplo:`C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Sites`?

Assim o comando `laravel new MyApp` instalará o Laravel em `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Sites\MyApp`.

Comment: Basicamente, como dito na resposta abaixo, o Laravel vai criar o projeto no diretório atual + nome do app como pasta. Basta você navegar com o console e pronto, mudou a pasta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O motivo disso é que o instalador do Laravel cria o projeto no diretório em que prompt de comandos ou terminal está sendo executado e por padrão quando você inicia o prompt de comandos ele abrirá no caminho `C:\Users\YourUser`, logo o projeto será criado nesse diretório.

Apesar de não existir uma maneira declarada ou simples de alterar o caminho padrão para a criação de projetos Laravel isso não é um problema pois existem várias formas de iniciar um projetos no diretório desejado:

## 1º Modo:

Simplesmente abra o prompt de comando e navegue até o diretório desejado usando o comando `cd`.
Exemplo:

```
cd Desktop\Sites
```

Assim se você navegar até o diretório  `C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\Sites` e usar o comando `laravel new MyApp` é nessa localização que será criado um diretório com o nome MyApp contendo a sua instalação do Laravel, ou seja você terá `C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\Sites\MyApp`.

## 2º Modo:

Abra o prompt no diretório desejado. O Windows permite navegar através do seu gerenciador de arquivos até a pasta desejada e ali abrir um prompt de comandos.

A maneira de fazer vai variar, mas no Windows 7 por exemplo, você **clica com o botão direito do mouse + shift** dentro do diretório e no menu de contexto terá a opção *Abrir prompt de comando aqui*. Ao selecionar essa opção você poderá criar o projeto dentro deste diretório.

## 3ª Modo:

Você pode dar o caminho completo para o projeto e os diretório que não existem serão criados pelo próprio instalador do Laravel.
Exemplo:

```
laravel new Desktop\Sites\MyApp
```

Os diretórios que não existem serão criados e o Laravel será instalado no último diretório, no caso o MyApp.